# What happens to the Software Center once Ubuntu switches to GNOME Software?

Tags: updates, software-center, installed-programs, 16.04, gnome-software

According to various news sources, GNOME Software is bound to replace the Ubuntu Software Center from 16.04 on.

I am still using at least one computer that is incapable of running a newer version than 12.04 and I was wondering, what happens to the programs that were installed through the Software Center on these machines running older Ubuntu versions?

Will the older systems receive GNOME Software through an update as well? Will the programs installed through the Ubuntu Software Center still be updated automatically in the future? Will it be dropped completely or still be running until the end of the 14.04 support cycle?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen No it isn't. April 2017 is EOL date for 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they will not receive gnome-software as an update. To get gnome-software as the replacement for software-center, you will have to upgrade to at least 16.04.

Any computer that you do not update to a version later than 12.04 only has about 13 more months of support. After that, they will receive no security updates.

As 14.04 is supported for 5 years, it has until sometime in April of 2019, but it will not receive any new features in software-center either.

And yes, any packages you have installed, will automatically be updated, if any updates are released for them, to the version of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I am still a little unsure, let's say I have VLC installed on a 14.04 machine (for simplicity), so in two years, the Ubuntu Software Center would still have a newer version of VLC in it, but if the developers decided to make a VLC2 in 2018, that would not be added to it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there. Software Center does not always have the latest version of apps. It is simply an interface to the Ubuntu archive and any PPAs added on your system. If you add a PPA with VLC2 in it, to your system in 2018, then it will show in software-center. However, "updates" in Ubuntu are not always new versions. They are security and bug fixes for the current version in Ubuntu, not necessarily new features.

Comment: Oh okay, I did not know that. I thought the software center worked a little bit different. Thanks for clarifying!